# Automatically change which element of array to display in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using React.

If I had an array like:

```
[ data: 
 title: foo1
  body: bar1

 title: foo2
  body: bar2

 title: foo3
  body: bar3
]
```

And I wanted to display a single `body` and `title` at one time on my page and loop through these elements (have a paragraph that changes its contents routinely).

So far I specify which data I want using this:

```
let specificBody = this.state.data[x].body; //loop through different elements of array on timer
      let specificTitle = this.state.data[x].title;
      let specificPosted_By = this.state.data[x].posted_by;
```

Is there any way to increment the value of x so that I can display a different body and title?  Or is there another way of achieving this aim?

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, make x into a state, snd then periodically change x.

Answer (score 1):

Some pseudo code, untested:

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => { /*todo reset at max value*/ setIndex(index+1) }, 10000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
},[])
```

and then use index here:

```
this.state.data[index].body;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how you can use setInterval to update the active index periodically.

Your render will then display the text of the active object in the array.

```
const data = [{ title, body },{ title, body }, { title, body }]

const Component = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
      //This is how you use setInterval to change the active index every 5 seconds
      setInterval(() => {
         setActive( previous => {
             if (previous === data.length) {
                return 0;
             } else {
                return previous+1;
             } 

         })


      }, 5000) //Change every 10 seconds

  },[])

  return <div>{data[0].title}</div>

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to accomplish two things:

1. Increment the specific array position
2. Do this automatically using a timer.

The snippet of code doesn't show what loop logic you're using, but assuming you're going to implement a setInterval inside a useEffect hook, you want to create an independent state variable for 'x' (which marks the array index on your data object).

You can then set a conditional within the useEffect hook, like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if(x <= data.length-1) {
       setData(data[x])
    }
    else {
      setState({
         x = 0;
   })
};
 x++;
}, 5000);
return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
}, [data, x])
```

Answer (score 0):

probably a better approach is to divide it into two components, one that hold the data and has the rotation logic and another one that is just presentation

something like this

```
const Article = (title, body) => {
  return <div>...</div>
}

const ArticleCarousel = (data, time) => {

 const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
 
 useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setIndex(i => (i + 1) % data.lenght)
}, time)
 return () => clearInterval(interval)
})

return <Article {...data[index]} />

}
```